# "UnExpected Token Illegal" Error Message when prepend to DOM element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am trying to prepend using jquery and i am getting Unexpected Token Illegal error message. Kindly help. Below is my code:

```
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <header>
      </header>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

My Javascript

```
var hamburger = "<button id='
hamburger1'><span class='
glyphicon - menu - hamburger '></span></button>";

var myapp = "<span class='app1'>My App</span><span class='app2'>|</span>";
 var myTopNav = hamburger + myapp;

jQuery('header').prepend(myTopNav);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are breaking the `hamburger` variable without adding the proper character to let the processor know you are continuing on the next line, which brings me to my next point:

There are 2 ways to break a Javascript string into new lines,

**Backslashes**:

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,\
consectetur adipisicing elit,\
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt\
ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
```

And the ever so popular, **plus sign** (concatenation):

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,"
    + "consectetur adipisicing elit,"
    + "sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt"
    + "ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.";
```

Comment: If you do want newlines in the strings, you can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#Multi-line_strings (in ES6)

Comment: I have fixed the problem. I have another question. How can i elimate jquery in this example and just use the plain javascript?
 jQuery('header').prepend(myTopNav);

Comment: @user5970552 Please don't ask two questions in one post. That makes your question less helpful to others

Comment: Done. Your answer fixed my issue Oliver. How do i replace the jquery statement jQuery('header').prepend(myTopNav); with the simple javascript in my codepen example?

Comment: `document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].innerHTML = myTopNav + document.getElementsByTagName("header")[0].innerHTML; `